# When developing the Yule-Walker equations, why can we assume $E(X_{t-k} \cdot Z_t) = 0$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, arima, stochastic-processes

I have a AR(1) process $X_t = 0.4X_{t-1} + Z_t$. I want to derive the Yule-Walker equation. I multiplied by $X_{t-k}$, took the expectation of both sides, and got:

$$E(X_{t-k}X_t) = 0.4E(X_{t-k}X_{t-1}) + E(X_{t-k}Z_t)$$

Tto proceed to the auto-covariance formulation, I was told I can assume that $E(X_{t-k}Z_t) = 0$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the generation of process $X_t$: at a specific time instant $t'$, we get the previous value, $X_{t'-1}$, multiply it with $0.4$ and add the input $Z_{t'}$ to obtain $X_{t'}$. So, we actually meet with the input $Z_{t'}$ at time $t=t'$, not any time before, and don't have an idea of what it is other than its prior distribution because $Z_t$ are assumed independent. This means, the value of $X_{t'}$ is obtained from all the current and previous inputs; i.e. $X_{t-k}$ is obtained from $Z_{t-k},Z_{t-k-1},\dots$ and so on. Logically, there is no reason to assume a statistical dependence between the current output and the future input, i.e. $X_{t-k}$ and $Z_t$ (or $X_{t}$ and $Z_{t+k}$), fork $k\geq 1$. When independent, $E[X_{t-k}Z_t]=E[X_{t-k}]E[Z_t]=0$, assuming $E[Z_t]=0$.